# sizeof in c++ showing string size one less

Tags: c++, string

In C++ I am trying to get size of a `string` say "gibbs";

When I am using `sizeof` function it is returning me size less then one of actual size.

I have below code :

```
 string s = "gibbs";
 cout << sizeof(s) <<endl;
```

and output is : 4. I guess it should be 5.

How to fix this issue. We can add +1 always to return of sizeof but will that be perfect solution ?

Comment: What is the value printed by `string s = "elephantine"; cout << sizeof(s) << endl;`?  Chances are, that is 4 too?

Comment: Which strange implementation has a 4--byte string like that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sizeof(s)` gives you the size of the object `s`, not the length of the string stored in the object `s`.

You need to write this:

```
cout << s.size() << endl;
```

Note that `std::basic_string` (and by extension `std::string`) has a `size()` member function. `std::basic_string` also has a `length` member function which returns same value as `size()`. So you could write this as well:

```
cout << s.length() << endl;
```

I personally prefer the `size()` member function, because the other containers from the standard library such as `std::vector`, `std::list`, `std::map`, and so on, have `size()` member functions but not `length()`. That is, `size()` is a uniform interface for the standard library container class templates. I don't need to remember it specifically for `std::string` (or any other container class template). The member function `std::string::length()` is a deviation in that sense.

Comment: @Hogan [`std::basic_string::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size)

Comment: fine, two versions after the last c++ I used.

Comment: I'm torn on the size/length issue. That's probably from my C background where length(strlen) is the number of characters being used now, and size(sizeof) is the maximum length (roughly). In many OO collection classes, these are known as length and capacity.

Comment: @paxdiablo: In the C++ standard containers, `size` is always the number of items currently stored in the container, while `capacity` is the currently allocated size. Of course, the C++ standard containers can be called "OO collection classes".

Answer (score 6):

`sizeof(s)` in your example is returning the size of `std::string`, there is no relation to the content of what its members point to.

> How to fix this issue. We can add +1 always to return of sizeof but will that be perfect solution?

no that won't solve anything because the value is constant, and `sizeof` is not providing the value you expect it does.

if you want to know the number of characters required for the character sequence of the string, you can use `s.length()` or `s.size()` -- add 1 to that value to know the size required for a terminated string.

also note that the value of `sizeof` is not going to be consistent across libraries and platforms. `std::string` implementations can vary greatly. in particular, you may see differences in pointer sizes and you may see small string optimizations.

Comment: ... which happens to be `4`, likely because it merely contains a pointer to some other data and addresses are 32-bit in the host environment.

Comment: @veer: It is unlikely that basic_string uses the pimpl idiom because it is a class template; and therefore the implementations of its members must be available in all translation units using basic_string (which sort of defeats the purpose of the pimpl idiom).

Answer (score 1):

Because that's the size of the string type on your system, not the size of the underlying data. For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main (void) {
    std::string s1 = "gibbs";
    std::string s2 = "a much longer string";
    std::cout << sizeof(s1) << '\n';
    std::cout << sizeof(s2) << '\n';

    std::cout << s1.length() << '\n';
    std::cout << s2.length() << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
4
4
5
20
```

In other words, you should be using `std::string::length()` to get the length of your strings.

Comment: In his system, std::string just happens to be the size of a pointer -- this is most likely a COW implementation which was banned in C++11. Most modern implementations are much larger than a pointer.

Comment: @BillyONeal see the c2wiki article on the [pimpl idiom](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom).

Comment: @veer: It is unlikely that `basic_string` uses the pimpl idiom because it is a class template; and therefore the implementations of its members must be available in all translation units using `basic_string` (which sort of defeats the purpose of the pimpl idiom).

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` returns the size of the type of the object, `std::string`, which happens to be `4` on your system. This *might* be because the implementation of `std::string` you're dealing with uses the [*pimpl idiom*](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom) -- i.e. it merely contains a pointer to the **real** implementation you're looking for,  and pointers *happen* to be 32-bit in your host environment. It's more likely, though, that you're using a [copy-on-write implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write#Other_applications_of_copy-on-write) of `std::string`, which no longer conforms to the specification as of the C++11 standard.

`std::string` is defined to be a specialization of the `std::basic_string` template class, in particular `std::basic_string<char>`; you should see the documentation on [`std::basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string). take a look at either [`std::basic_string::size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/size) and [`std::basic_string::length`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/length).

```
std::string s = "stackoverflow";
std::assert(s.size() == 13);
```

Comment: As I said elsewhere, the pimpl idiom is unlikely here. It is much more likely that the OP is using an implementation of basic_string which does copy-on-write, which was banned in C++11. Modern implementations are typically at least 3x `sizeof(void*)`, to store begin, end, and capacity pointers. Implementations which do the small string optimization (e.g. dinkumware)larger.

Comment: @BillyONeal ah, thanks, that makes sense. I recall reading about `std::move`.

Comment: Thank you friends, I am noob in C++, your support is much appreciated.