# Different size of string showing when going by two different methods

Tags: c++, string

when I go by this:

```
string s="hello";
cout<<sizeof(s);
```

Then it shows 4 as the answer, but when I go for some individual value:

```
string s="hello";
cout<<sizeof(s[2]);
```

It shows 1 as output. Going by this output the answer of 1st should be 5 as there are five characters in the string. Where am I wrong? (I ran this on Ideone).

Comment: See the [`sizeof operator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof)

Comment: `sizeof()` of a `std::string` is not the number of characters in the string. It's the size of the `std::string` class in bytes. The size is the same whether the `std::string` is empty, or has a thousands of characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sizeof()` returns the **compile-time** byte size of the *type* of the specified parameter.

The `s` variable is an instance of the `std::string` class, so `sizeof(s)` returns the byte size of the `std::string` class itself, which is 4 in a 32-bit executable (8 in a 64-bit executable) because the `std::string` class contains a single data member that is a pointer to the allocated character data.  If you want to know how many characters are allocated for the string at **run-time**, use the `std::string::size()` method instead.  That will return the 5 you are looking for.

`s[2]` returns a `char`, so `sizeof(s[2])` returns the byte size of the `char` type, which is 1.

Answer (score 0):

The [`sizeof` operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) gives the memory (in bytes) taken up by the given type or expression. For a primitive type, this is straightforward. For a class/struct, it returns the number of bytes taken up by the fields of the struct themselves, not necessarily pointed-to data; it will be the same for every instance of that type.

See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12119659/1848578).

**Examples:**

```
sizeof(char) // 1
sizeof(9001) // sizeof(int), usually 4

struct mystring {
    const char* data;
};

mystring foo = {"foo"};
sizeof(mystring) // probably sizeof(const char*), depending on packing; let's say 4
sizeof(foo)      // will always be same as above; 4
foo.data = "cornbread is tasty";
sizeof(foo)      // the struct itself still takes up the same amount of space; 4
```