# String Task Codeforces Problem - https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/118/A

Tags: c++17

https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/118/A
my code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    for(int i=0; i<sizeof(str); i++)
    {
        if(str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
            str[i]+=32;
        {
            if(str[i] >= 'a' && str[i] <= 'z' && str[i] != 'a' && str[i] != 'e' && str[i] != 'i' && str[i] != 'o' && str[i] != 'u' && str[i] != 'A' && str[i] != 'E' && str[i] != 'I' && str[i] != 'O' && str[i] != 'U')

                cout << "." << str[i];
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Where is the problem in this code because it gives wrong when I submit?

I am not seeing any problem, could anyone help me to detect?

Comment: `sizeof(str)` doesn't do what you think it does. Note, codeforces or any similar site will not teach you C++.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sizeof in c++ showing string size one less](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12119645/sizeof-in-c-showing-string-size-one-less)

Answer (score 0):

In the question they have included 'y' as a vowel too. I changed some other stuff too (like, use i<str.size() not i<sizeof(str) ), try the following code it will get accepted :

```
int main()
{
    string str;
    cin >> str;
    for(int i=0; i<str.size(); i++)
    {
        char temp;
        temp = str[i];
        if(temp >= 'A' && temp <= 'Z')
            temp = tolower(temp);    

        if(temp != 'a' && temp != 'e' && temp != 'i' && temp != 'o' && temp != 'u' &&  temp != 'y')
            cout << "." << temp;

    }
    return 0;
}
```